# Jquery Magnifier Disappear after click to next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

Im using BookFlip v4 and also Dynamic Drive Power Zoomer to do a project.Basically its an online mag with rollover zoom in feature.

I configured everything correctly, DDPZ will zoom on the first page, but after i flip to next page, it disappears and if i go back to the main page via navigation button, it will not show up. I suspect its not loading the script after you press the button. help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready


//EXAMPLE 1:
//$('#myimage').addpowerzoom()

//EXAMPLE 2:
$('#bookflip img').addpowerzoom({
    defaultpower: 2,
    powerrange: [2,7],
    largeimage: null,
    magnifiersize: [200,200] //<--no comma following last option!
})

})


</script>
```

below is the images that i am targeting:

```
<div id="bookflip">
</div>

 </div>
<div id="pages" style="width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="background-color:white;"></div>


    <div name="Front"><img src="images/KWC-Raya1.jpg" /></div>

    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya2.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya3.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya4.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya5.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya6.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya7.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya8.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya9.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya10.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya11.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya12.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya13.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya14.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya15.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya16.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya17.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya18.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya19.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya20.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/KWC-Raya21.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the function mytest() is applyed only on the first image/page, i think it should be on all pages :

```
<div><img onclick="myTest()">...</div>
```

also the line

```
$('#bookflip img').addpowerzoom({ ...
```

is applyed to an empty div (id:`bookflip`) on document ready.

```
<div id="bookflip">
</div>
```

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pages img').addpowerzoom();
});
```

or we can wait for bookflip to build its elements and apply the powerzoom on window load:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
  $('#bookflip img').addpowerzoom(); 
});
```

Comment: the div under bookflip will be autogenerated by javascript.

so it will be bookflip #p3 img.

Comment: tried it . nothing. i see that the power zoomer doesnt change the image in its code. meaning that if i skip/flip to next image, it still keep the settings for pic 1 zoom.